# If $f(x)$ has a minimum at (3,2) what does $y = \frac{5}{3+f(x)}$ have at x = 3?

Tags: functions

No calculus allowed.

I can get the value by substituting 2 for $f(3)$, and that it should be a maximum turning point as $f(x+\delta h)$ and $f(x -\delta h) > f(x)$ but am not sure how to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already stated the result. If $f$ has a minimum at $(3,2)$, then for some interval $I$ containing $3$, $f(x)\ge 2$ for all $x\in I$.

We know $y(3)=1$, and for any $x\in I$, since $3+f(x)\ge 5$,

$$y(x)=\frac{5}{3+f(x)}\le \frac{5}{5}=1.$$

So on the same interval $y$ is less than $1$, i.e., $y$ has a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=y=5/(3+f(x))$. For any $x$, we have
$$
3+f(x)\geq3+f(3)=3+2=5>0\implies g(x)=\frac{5}{3+f(x)}\leq\frac{5}{3+f(3)}=g(3).
$$
And so $y=g(x)$ is everywhere defined (because $3+f(x)>0$ always; see above) and has a global maximum at $x=3$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$f(3)=2, f(3+\varepsilon)>2; f(3-\varepsilon)>2$$

$$y=\frac{5}{3+f(x)}$$
$$y(3)=\frac5{3+2}=1$$
$$y(3+\varepsilon)<\frac5{3+2}=1$$
$$y(3-\varepsilon)<\frac5{3+2}=1$$
Then $g(x)$ has a maximum in $(3;1)$